# Get Activity from Service (Daydream)

Tags: android, facebook, android-simple-facebook

I'm trying to make a daydream that uses the Facebook SDK with Android-Simple-Facebook.

Daydreams run as a service and has no associated activity as far as I am aware. I'm having an issue where I need to pass an Activity (not a context...) through to Android-Simple-Facebook, which passes it to the Facebook SDK. I drilled through some of the methods and found this one to to be the issue:

```
public UiLifecycleHelper(android.app.Activity activity
    com.facebook.Session.StatusCallback callback) { /* compiled code */ }
```

I am not sure how I can use this anymore if I don't have an activity. I can understand using this to help with the "lifecycle" but it seems like a terrible decision to use Activity instead of Context.

The code that doesn't work in mine is:

```
mSimpleFacebook = SimpleFacebook.getInstance(this); //this needs to be activity, 
    not DreamService, which extends Context
```

I tried

```
Activity activity = new Activity();
mSimpleFacebook = SimpleFacebook.getInstance(activity);
```

but further down the line its trying to get a context which it can't.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 
'android.content.Context android.content.Context.getApplicationContext()' 
on a null object reference
```

Anyone have any ideas? This is going to be a serious dealbreaker if I can't get it to work.

Comment: To make any request to facebook side, you have to get `accessToken`. Once you have it, you can do most of actions without `Activity` at all. To get the `accessToken` you need to take the user through login process with login dialog and stuff like this. So my question, how and where will you do the login process?

Comment: I have that in the settings activity. That part works fine, your project works well for that. But the main SimpleFacebook() method that gets an instance requires an Activity parameter.

Comment: I see, you are right,.. ok, I will need to do some small changes to support this scenario

Comment: I'm using v2.0 of your repo. Thanks!